# What does non-zero integer mean?

Tags: terminology

The definition for the **Rational Number** is given as **Numbers that can be expressed as a fraction of an integer and a non-zero integer.** at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers#cite_note-1

What does non-zero integer mean?

Comment: It means an integer that's not zero.

Comment: Not equal to zero for rationals we can't divide by zero so it needs to be non zero.

Comment: -1, -2, 1, 3, 5, 7 are all examples of non-zero integers. 0 however is zero and not non-zero...

Comment: do you know what zero is? do you know what non is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integer is any whole number or its negative, e.g. ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...

A non-zero integer is any of these but 0.

Your definition of a rational number is just a mathematically rigorous way of saying that a rational number is any fraction of whole numbers, possibly with negatives, and you can't have 0 in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Set of all integer is $\mathbb{Z=}${$0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3, \ldots\ldots,\pm{1000 \ldots}$}. So just remove $0$ from $\mathbb{Z}$. Rest any of these infinite numbers can be used.